# No such module 'Firebase' , cannot import Firebase Into Swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, swift4.2

I am building an iOS app and it is my first experience using Firebase database. In Xcode 10.1 and swift version 4.2, I am trying to import Firebase into my classes. In a swift file, I have imported the database by "import Firebase".

But unfortunately, I am getting an error that says  No such module 'Firebase’.

This is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Jawwab' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'EstimoteProximitySDK', '~> 1.0'
  # Pods for Jawwab
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the pods and open the workspace instead of the project?

Answer (score 2):

it's a common error in XCode, just try to **clean and build** your project, usually it helps. If it doesn't:

Option 1: check your "**podfile**" file once again, and then run `$ pod install`.

Option 2: delete derived data files of your project and then rebuild it.

Option 3: close your xcworkspace file, and then deintegrate your pod files (run `$ pod deintegrate`) and then run `$ pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just try again by saving **podfile** and `run pod install` command again.
2. Also check and confirm that you have selected all **targets** f your project while adding **pods**.