# no such module 'firebase' error occurring in macbook m1

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I have tried every possible answer on this site but none of them have worked. I have added a pod file but after I import Firebase, I keep getting the (No such module 'Firebase') error

i am using Macbook Air with M1

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

and here is what my pod file looks like

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end

# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '7.2-M1'
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488563/no-such-module-firebase-cannot-import-firebase-into-swift-4

Comment: tried this not working

Comment: Try building the project to prime the Xcode module cache.

Answer (score 0):

try this 1)cleaning the derived data
2)Force Quite Xcode
3)Check if you get any errors while installing the pods
4) Instead of importing Firebase try
`import FirebaseCore`
Tell me how this goes for you?
Are you using Coredata in your project??

Comment: are you using core data ?

Comment: yes i tried adding that but that didn't worked

Comment: hey that's the problem , I had similar issue but when I removed core data from my project it was working fine , Maybe there is a better fix but this helped me

Comment: i removed import Firebase and FirebaseApp.configure(), just used flutter clean and the issue got resolved.